# Rename tag UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I suggest renaming the existing tag [uitableviewautomaticdim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uitableviewautomaticdim) to [uitableviewautomaticdimension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uitableviewautomaticdimension) on Stack Overflow.

Reason: The tag is an unusual cut off version of the iOS constant `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very sensible proposal, now that [we can have tag names as long as 35 characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299490). I'd say fitting in the full name of the class is definitely a wise use of those extra 10 characters.

So, this is now done. The tag is renamed to [uitableviewautomaticdimension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uitableviewautomaticdimension).

You should see it live immediately, save perhaps for caching effects.